# Http request for file download stops JQuery ajax calls

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

**Problem:**

On the site I am building, I have two JQuery ajax long polling calls constantly pending.
I am now trying to put in a file download feature, so that when  link is pressed the user is prompted with the SaveAs box. This download of the file is working fine, the problem is that when the link is pressed the two ajax calls are cancelled.

I am trying either not have the ajax calls cancelled or the possibility of setting up the ajax calls straight away.

Here is the code for the link:

HTML:

```
<a href="/test" id="testfile">Tasks</a>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click',"#testfile",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var href=$(this).attr('href');
    window.location.href = href;
    updater();                               /* AJAX CALL #1 */
    notifier();                              /* AJAX CALL #2 */
});
```

**What I have tried:**

I the code above I was trying to call the two ajax calls after starting the download. This is not working. If I put in some delay so that the calls are initiated after the download is complete then it works but seeing as the files can be big and therefore take an unknown amount of time to receive this is of course a bad solution.

I am really confused as to why the ajax calls are being cancelled? Is this because the page is being unloaded when I press the link?

Seeing as I am only running on a development server with one thread, the new ajax calls  that I am trying to set up right after following the link might be failing because the server is busy, could this be the case?

---

**SOLVED:**

I added a hidden iframe to the buttom of the site and with targeted that with my link. I also removed the JS code, since the ajax calls are now not being cancelled.

The code is now looking like this:

HTML:

```
<a href="/test" target="filetargetframe"  id="testfile">Tasks</a>

********

<iframe name="filetargetframe" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

Comment: `window.location.href` changes the page, and that cancels everything. Try creating an `iframe` with src=href, maybe it will work.

Comment: So eventhough the window.location.href in my case does not change the page but just initiated a download of a file the browser still sees it as a changed page and therefore stops the ajax calls? How can I go around this with an iframe?

Comment: No, it doesn't change the page if it's a download. You could try using an iframe, but is suspect you'll have the same issue. To use an iframe, place an iframe on your page, hide it(optional), and then add target="theiframeid" to the anchor tag and stop preventing the default action. (and stop changing the location.href, let the default action of an anchor click do that)

Comment: @KevinB That seemed to work. The ajax calls are not being cancelled now. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky should post that (the 2nd half of the comment) as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the answer from yoavmatchulsky the problem was solved:

I added a hidden iframe to the buttom of the site and with targeted that with my link. I also removed the JS code, since the ajax calls are now not being cancelled.

The code is now looking like this:

HTML:

```
<a href="/test" target="filetargetframe"  id="testfile">Tasks</a>

********

<iframe name="filetargetframe" style="display:none"></iframe>
```